# How do I assign params.get('brand') to a variable in the following function?

Tags: angular

I am attempting to assign the result of `params.get('brand')` to the variable `brandName` within the map method but it is not working. How can I do this?

```
private getProducts() {
    this.products$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params:ParamMap) => this.brandName = params.get('brand')),
      switchMap((params:ParamMap) => 
         this.dataService.getProductsByBrand(params.get('brand')))      
    )
    this.products$.subscribe(products => {
      this.setProducts(products);
      console.log('products', this.products)
    })    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example link would help.

You can use `rxjs`'s `tap` operator for side effects.

e.g.

```
 this.products$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap((params:ParamMap) => this.brandName = params.get('brand')),
      switchMap((params:ParamMap) => 
         this.dataService.getProductsByBrand(params.get('brand')))      
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

try following snippet and check if works for you

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

}

private getProducts() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
         this.brandName = params['brand']; //read the param brand from route
         this.dataService.getProductsByBrand(this.brandName).subscribe(products => {
           this.setProducts(products);
           console.log('products', this.products)
       }) 
    });
```

Comment: OP is clearly using a reactive approach to the problem. This answer doesn't really answer the question he/she is asking.